# Rails model has_many association to the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, migration, associations, activemodel

I have two models: `Category` and `Subcategory`

And I can have situation that **Subcategory** will include more **Subcategories**

How Can I do it with rails associations?

Now my code:

**category.rb**

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subcategories, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

**subcategory.rb**

```
class Subcategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :products, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Possible example:

`Category` **Readable** --> `Subcategory` **Books** --> `Subcategory` **Books for kids** --> products

Comment: Books for kids will be only under a subcategory or it can be even under a category? Like `Category` Readable --> `Subcategory` Books for kids is this case possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good case for a polymorphic `belongs_to` association.

```
#on Subcategory model
belongs_to :parent, polymorphic: true
has_many :subcategories, as: :parent, dependent: :destroy

#on Category model
has_many :subcategories, as: :parent, dependent: :destroy


#on the database
t.references :parent, polymorphic: true, index: true # this adds two columns, parent_id and parent_type
```

Now you can assign anything anything as the parent for a subcategory and you can call `subcategory.parent` to get either a Category or a Subcategory

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Comment: Worked! 1) rails generate migration AddParentRefToSubcategories parent:references     2) open and edit migration to `add_reference :subcategories, :parent, polymorphic: true, index: true`   3) rake db:migrate   4)profit

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add subcategory_id to your subcategory model by migration and add `has_many :subcategories` in your subcategory model.
Or you can add 
`belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Subcategory", :foreign_key => "parent_subcategory_id"
  has_many :child_subcategories, :class_name => "Subcategory", :foreign_key => "child_subcategory_id"`